# non-explicit extension of classes?

Tags: php, oop, class, extension-methods

**Scenario**
The *system* has classes declared in `/system/classes/`.
The *application*  has classes declared in `/application/classes/`.

If there is class in the *application* folder that has the same name as a class in the *system* folder then the class in the *application* folder should extend the class in the *system* folder.

Not all classes in the *system* folder will be overwritten by a class in the *application* folder.

**Question**
How can you cause the class in the *system* folder to extend the class in the *application* class **only** if there is a class in the *application* folder.

**NB:** All classes that can be overwritten are static classes
**NB:** Even if we have to name the *application* classes *my_className* it is fine, as long as we can still just call `className::functionName()`

I guess Im looking for something similar to how Code Igniter does it.

---

**Edit**

Example Class
The below class is used as a loader to load in all other classes (be they libraries, processes or other). It is also used to load in css/image/js files ect.

If the user was to extend the class they might want to add an `ini()` function which would be used to load in `ini` files.

```
class load {

    protected static $helpers;
    protected static $configs;
    protected static $libraries;
    protected static $processes;
    protected static $js;
    protected static $css;

    public static function init() {
        self::$helpers = new stdClass();
        self::$libraries = new stdClass();
        self::$configs = new stdClass();
        self::$processes = new stdClass();
        self::$css = new stdClass();
        self::$js = new stdClass();
    }

    public static function config($name) {
        if (isset(self::$configs->$name) && is_object(self::$configs->$name))
            return self::$configs->$name;

        if (is_file(CONFIG_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
            require_once(CONFIG_DIR . $name . '.php');
            self::$configs->$name = new $name();
            return self::$configs->$name;
        }
        throw new exception('Could not load config file \'' . $name . '\'');
        return false;
    }

    public static function helper($name) {
        if (isset(self::$helpers->$name) && is_object(self::$helpers->$name))
            return self::$helpers->$name;

        if (is_file(APP_HELPER_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
            require_once(APP_HELPER_DIR . $name . '.php');
            self::$helpers->$name = new $name();
            return self::$helpers->$name;
        }

        if (is_file(HELPER_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
            require_once(HELPER_DIR . $name . '.php');
            self::$helpers->$name = new $name();
            return self::$helpers->$name;
        }
        throw new exception('Could not load helper file \'' . $name . '\'');
        return false;
    }

    public static function library($name, $params = array()) {
        if (empty($params) && isset(self::$libraries->$name) && is_object(self::$libraries->$name))
            return self::$libraries->$name;

        if (is_file(APP_LIBRARY_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
            require_once(APP_LIBRARY_DIR . $name . '.php');
            self::$libraries->$name = new $name($params);
            return self::$libraries->$name;
        }

        if (is_file(LIBRARY_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
            require_once(LIBRARY_DIR . $name . '.php');
            self::$libraries->$name = new $name();
            return self::$libraries->$name;
        }
        throw new exception('Could not load library file \'' . $name . '\'');
        return false;
    }

    public static function process($name, $args = array()) {
        if (isset(self::$processes->$name) && is_object(self::$processes->$name))
            return self::$processes->$name;

        if (is_file(PROCESS_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
            require_once(PROCESS_DIR . $name . '.php');
            if (empty($args)) {
                self::$processes->$name = new $name();
                return self::$processes->$name;
            } else {
                self::$processes->$name = new ReflectionClass($name);
                return self::$processes->$name->newInstanceArgs($args);
            }
        }
        throw new exception('Could not load process file \'' . $name . '\'');
        return false;
    }

    public static function css($name) {
        if (isset(self::$css->$name) && !empty(self::$css->$name))
            return self::$css->$name;

        self::$css->$name = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . CSS_PATH . $name . '.css">';
        return self::$css->$name;
    }

    public static function js($name) {
        if (isset(self::$js->$name))
            return self::$js->$name;

        self::$js->$name = '<script src="' . JS_PATH . $name . '.js"></script>';
        return self::$js->$name;
    }

    public static function template($name, $vars = array()) {
        if (is_file(TEMPLATE_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
            ob_start();
            if (!empty($vars))
                extract($vars);
            require(TEMPLATE_DIR . $name . '.php');
            $contents = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $contents;
        }
        throw new exception('Could not load template file \'' . $name . '\'');
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: PHP follows the static object orientation paradigm, it's not protoype-based (and classes aren't first class objects so to say). The only way to accomplish this is via e.g. [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) features.

Comment: You won't be able to implicitly *extend* classes this way. It'd be simple to write a system that automatically *loads* one or the other class through.

Comment: Hmm, I get the feeling I am using static classes wrong, Maybe I should explain the sort of classes a bit better and you can tell me if I am?

Comment: Yes, show some of the intended API. Maybe it can be accomplished or structured another way. Right now it sounds like you are just using static classes as function holders. If so a better alternative might be to use the <non-charming-adverb-here> namespace syntax for grouping them.

Comment: Why can't the application classes simply extend the system classes?

Comment: because then you would have to call eg `my_load` instead of just being able to call `load` or as a better example, extending the dbResult class to add a function that returns the result as an object instead of an array. it would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know code Igniter do replace classes, rather than extending them.

The more pratical way is to dinamically generate the code:

```
$code = file_get_contents($appFile);
if ( file_exists( $systemFile ) )
{
    //don't do this ! Just a proof of concept, use regexp or code tokenizer
    //you will also need to programmatically determine MyClass and SystemClass
    $code = str_replace ('class myClass', 'class MyClass extends SystemClass', $code);
}
eval ($code)
```

Please note that eval is generally considered evil for good reasons, so be sure to double check your code.
You may want to re-think your framework design instead.

**UPDATE:** if classes are just statical you may want to look into the **[Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)** pattern and __call() __get() __set(). That may suffice and avoid the eval() route.